# Read full line without getline(), fgets or scanf()

Tags: arduino, scanf, gnu, fgets, stdio

i have a short question for some standard problem.

How can I **read a full line** from a receive buffer **without** getline(), fgets or scanf().

Because its not availble in the arduino enviroment.

I get only one sign, after saving data into message. Here my code:

```
message = ((char)LoRa.read());
```

With the serial monitor it works fine to receiv and print the full line from the sender.

Thanks so much :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vBsz.jpg)

Tried to find some libs for using getline(), fgets or scanf() in arduino ide. But it couldnt work

Comment: what is the `LoRa` object?

Comment: You found readBytesUntil() and readStringUntil() ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:

```
char incomingMessage[200];
String receivedLine;
uint16_t pointer = 0;
bool lineReceived = false;
  
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    memset(incomingMessage, NULL, sizeof(incomingMessage));
    receivedLine.reserve(200);
}
  
void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        incomingMessage[pointer] = (char)Serial.read();
        pointer++;

        if (incomingMessage[pointer] == '\n') {
            lineReceived = true;
        }
    }

    if (lineReceived) {
        lineReceived = false;
        receivedLine = "";
        pointer = 0;
        receivedLine = incomingMessage;
        memset(incomingMessage, NULL, sizeof(incomingMessage));
    }
}
```

Comment: a complicated  and inefficient way

Comment: `pointer`  should be reset somewhere. And `Serial.readStringUntil('\n');` does a similar job.